# Rails plugin for User reg, password recovery, the works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there such a plugin for rails that will do everything for user registrations, or must this all be coded from the ground up using various plugins and combining them or just coding some parts by hand?

Answer (score 4):

Check out [AuthLogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) and [Devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

These will handle all the registration, login, logout, password reset etc for you. 
You still have to do *some* work, but the logic itself is done for you.

Comment: I haven't used Devise yet, but I'll second the recommendation for authlogic. It's good stuff.

Comment: And for generic gems/plugins like these, checkout ruby-toolbox: http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication.html

Comment: Does this handle password recovery? Seems like a lifesaver kind of feature.

Comment: Yep, you can have a unique token generated and a link associated with it for the token-based access to password reset etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Rails noob, and of all the authentication gems, I found [Devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to be by far the least confusing to learn how to use. Ryan Bates's [Railscast on Devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise) is a great help as well.

Be sure to install the correct gem for the version of Rails you're using.